# Karma + Rails: File structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, karma-runner

When using the *karma* javascript test library (née Testacular) together with Rails, where should test files and mocked data go be placed?

It seems weird to have them in /assets/ because we don’t actually want to serve them to users. (But I guess if they are simply never precompiled, then that’s not an actual problem, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up putting tests and mocked data under the Rails app’s `spec` folder and configuring Karma to import them as well as our tested code from `app/assets`.

Works for us. Other thoughts are welcome.

Our `config/karma.conf.js` file:

```js
basePath = '../';

files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,

  //libs
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular-*.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/underscore-min.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-strap/angular-strap.min.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-ui/angular-ui.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-0.2.0.min.js',

  //our app!
  'app/assets/javascripts/<our-mini-app>/**',

  // and our tests
  'spec/javascripts/<our-mini-app>/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'spec/javascripts/<our-mini-app>/unit/*.coffee',
  // mocked data
  'spec/javascripts/<our-mini-app>/mocked-data/<data-file>.js.coffee',
];

autoWatch = true;

browsers = 'PhantomJS'.split(' ')

preprocessors = {
  '**/*.coffee': 'coffee'
}
```

Comment: I created a folder /spec/angular where I put every test file, having /spec/angular/e2e, /spec/angular/unit, etc... But how did you config the karma.conf.js? I'm not sure if the proxies attribute is right: `proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:3000/'
};` I'm having errors to run even a simple test, it's like javascript sources to test are not included.

Comment: PD: I'm working with legacy code that uses application.js.erb as manifest for all javascript files, even angular application, in my karma.conf.js I have `files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  '../../app/assets/javascripts/application.js',
  '*/*Spec.js'
];`

Comment: BTW I'm testing if a module called "StSelector" is there and it works ( http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-testacular.html#testing-modules ), and I'm getting `Midway: Testing Modules StSelector Module: should be registered FAILED
 Error: No module: StSelector`

Comment: @p1nox Updated with our karma conf

Comment: I found the reason why karma couldn't find my application.js manifest file, as it is a .erb file and it can't be read without the Rails server running, so I started the server and in the karma.conf.js I had to reference directly to that file `'http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js'`

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/karma-users/asset$20pipeline/karma-users/f7IgTjJphbA/FXikUOSb6yMJ

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/karma-users/pipeline/karma-users/f7IgTjJphbA/FXikUOSb6yMJ (the previous link was broken)

Comment: This is an interesting approach, what I don't like is that it doesn't fully account for the asset pipeline (you may have ERB javascript files and such). A more robust solution would have to integrate with the pipeline somehow.

Comment: @ChrisNicola If you figure out something better, I will certainly change my accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

Via this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Mg8YjKWbEJ8

I'm experimenting with something that looks like this:

```js
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js',
  'spec/javascripts/*_spec.coffee',
  {
    pattern: 'app/assets/javascripts/*.{js,coffee}',
    watched: true,
    included: false,
    served: false
  }
],
```

It watches app js files, but doesn't include them or serve them, instead including the application.js served by rails and sprockets.

I've also been fiddling with https://github.com/lucaong/sprockets-chain , but haven't found a way to use requirejs to include js files from within gems (such as jquery-rails or angularjs-rails).

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I'm guessing it's a bit slower than the solution @alan-h suggests though.

Comment: I liked this solution. It solves the problem for loading files that has .js.erb as well.

Comment: How did you include `angular-mocks.js` using this approach? I don't see it in the list of files at all. I added it to my list of files, but it looks like this: `/home/tylercollier/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-assets-angular-mocks-1.2.15/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js`. This is not only gross, long, and now I have to keep it up to date, it doesn't work for any developer but me.

Comment: I ended up combining the strategy of this answer with the rake task described [here](http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular--rails-with-no-fuss.html), which grabs asset file names from sprockets.

Answer (score 3):

I found this project helpful as a starting point. https://github.com/monterail/rails-angular-karma-example. It is explained by the authors [on their blog](http://codetunes.com/2014/karma-on-rails/).

It's an example rails app with angular.js and karma test runner.